# How to animate a robot like a character in a 3D animation movie?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I would like to handle animation sequences for a robot. Is there a way to manage this using a ROS package?

Here are the features that I would expect from such a package:

- manage a sequence "data container" for sequences manipulation
- read this container to activate the robot joints
- view/edit this container
- generate containers from recordings
- generate containers with tools similar to a 3D graphics animation software (like Blender or Maya), using keyframes or IK

I have found this one, which looks in line with my requirement, but unfortunately for the PR2 only: http://wiki.ros.org/puppet

Bags could be also a part of the solution (data container management): http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag

Any feedback appreciated, could it be a similar requirement, documentations, contact, etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96416/how-to-animate-a-robot-like-a-character-in-a-3d-animation-movie?/) by [Arn-O](https://answers.ros.org/users/5387/arn-o/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use Maya, make sure to check out this open source plugin:
https://github.com/AutodeskRoboticsLab/Mimic

---

Originally posted by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) with karma: 184 on 2018-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-14**:
This is a nice plugin, but the OP specifically asked for a ROS package to do this. Your suggestion is Maya only.